# Using Compass sprite generation on localhost

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sprite

I work on my local machine on Windows 8. I use XAMPP.

I am trying to generate a sprite and use it in my project with Compass & Sass. The sprite generates successfully, as I can see it in my images folder, but when trying to use the sprite, I get a 404 error for the sprite.

It keeps trying to get the images from localhost. `http://localhost/images/cb-s2d817fe88b.png` for example.

But my project is located in `http://localhost/projects`.Here's my config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

And here's an example of my SCSS:

@import "../images/cb/*.png";

```
.logo {
    @include cb-sprite('logo');
}
```

How can I reference the sprite successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem, the issue is that your config file is not being refreshed after you made changes to it. You can do so on you terminal or command line interface

just cd to the project folder, then do "compass config --force" which should overwrite you current config file with the changes and that should fix it.

Also I realize this question has been open a couple of years ago now, so my apologies if the answer has already been found.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `http_path` in your `.config-rb` file in your compass root directory to reflect the path to your sprite folder:

`http_path = "/projects/"`

If that does not work, remove `../images/` from your import statement. Compass should already be looking in whatever directory is set as `images_dir`

Note: If you are actively "watching" a compass folder, you will have to start and stop it for this change to be reflected.

Ultimately, the best solution for this is to configure a virtual host and domain for your project (that way files will be able to be root `/` relative), but this should be a quick fix.

Comment: Okay so I changed the "/" path the images are still going to the same url.

Comment: Hmmm. You can try adding a declaration for the ``http_generated_images_path`` to your config.rb file. That will force the generated sprite css to use that path.

Comment: Nope/ It does not change the path at all, like it's cached. Tried to remove sasscache but still didn't do anything.

Comment: Just for kicks, can you try changing any of those settings to "foo" or something strange, to make sure that the config file is actually affecting things. Otherwise it might be a ruby related path issue.